# WCF service not returning complete object in Json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf

```
[OperationContract]
    public FareDataModel GetFareAndDistanceJson(string source, string destination, string country, string city)
    {
       return  FareManager.GetFare(source, destination, country, city);


    }
```

I have above method in my svc class.But this is not able to completely send data in Json.I get below result

```
 {
"d": {
    "__type": "FareDataModel:#MeterupAutoTaxiWebService",
    "Fares": [
        {
            "__type": "VehicleFare:#MeterupAutoTaxiWebService"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

But when I return it as string I get the data but in form of string.I really want to get json.
Here is my FareDataModel object

```
 [DataContract]
    public class FareDataModel
    {
        public string SourceAddress;
        public string DestinationAddress;
        public int Duration;
        public int Distance;
        public string Error;

        [DataMember]
        public List<VehicleFare> Fares = new List<VehicleFare>();
    }


    [DataContract]
    public class VehicleFare
    {
        public string PhoneNo;
        public string Vehicle;
        public double Fare;
    }
```

I tried all the changes that are explained in one of the post but nothing is working for me.
When I return as string by modifying my code as below

```
[OperationContract]
    public string GetFareAndDistanceJson(string source, string destination, string country, string city)
    {

       return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(FareManager.GetFare(source, destination, country, city));

    }
```

I get Following result

```
    {
    "d": "{\"SourceAddress\":\"Majestic, Bangalore, Karnataka, India\",\"DestinationAddress\":\"Marathahalli Market, Bangalore, Karnataka, India\",\"Duration\":2475,\"Distance\":19872,\"Error\":null,\"Fares\":[{\"PhoneNo\":null,\"Vehicle\":\"Auto\",\"Fare\":238}]}"
}
```

I really need a true json response.

Here is my class

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1
{



    [OperationContract]
    public string GetFareAndDistanceJson(string source, string destination, string country, string city)
    {

       return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(FareManager.GetFare(source, destination, country, city));

    }
    // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
}
```

Please help me out.

My webconfig

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="MeterupAutoTaxiWebService.Service1">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MeterupAutoTaxiWebService.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior"
                    binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MeterupAutoTaxiWebService.Service1" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>

            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MeterupAutoTaxiWebService.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior">
              <enableWebScript/>

                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
            multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MeterupAutoTaxiEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MeterupTaxiAutoEntities.csdl|res://*/MeterupTaxiAutoEntities.ssdl|res://*/MeterupTaxiAutoEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=MeterupAutoTaxi;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `[DataMember]` to other properties, you want?

Comment: Thanks It worked after adding [DataMember]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked after adding [DataMember] to each.It was returning valid XML without adding this when I request for XML.But I had to add this for returning json